# Fastapi set old values to variable before new values update

Tags: python, fastapi

I am using fastapi, and trying to get a record from database, and update that record.
But before update, I want to set those values to a variable and use it for logging purpose.
Now when I update the db its updating the new variable as well

```
qry = select(Item) \
            .where(Item.id == request.id)
        item = db.scalars(qry).first()
        **old_item=item**
        item.tag = request.tags[0]
        db.add(item)
        db.commit()
```

after save, values in item and old item is same.
How am I  going to do this?

Comment: The problem with your current solution is that assigning an object to a variable doesn't make a deep copy of the object - they're still the same object. Generally you should be able to convert the object to a dict: `old_item = dict(item)` - this will create a new object (a dict) with its own values.